# Creating a dynamic list with R to use it in shiny

Tags: r, list, append, shiny

I need to format a list so that the list items are displayed as radio buttons on my shiny application. Below is an example of how my list is currently formatted:

```
mylist = list("Choice 1"=1, "Choice 2"=2, "Choice 3"=3)
```

The list should be generated dynamically. The list will be queried to determine the correct name so as to replace "Choice 1", "Choice 2" and "Choice 3".

I have tried to use `list<-append` but it doesn't interpret the variable name. Example:

```
var = "SimpleTest"
mylist=list()
mylist<-append(mylist,list(var=1))
```

Current Output:

```
# $var
# [1] 1
```

My desired output is:

```
$SimpleTest
[1] 1
```

Comment: Try `mylist<-append(mylist,setNames(list(1),var))`

Comment: Oh thanks you very much, its been 3hours I'm on this problem !

Comment: Glad it helped. Another option: `mylist[[var]]<-1`.

Comment: @KingOfBabu Does my answer below solve you question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem here how I solved it:

```
varnames <-c("Choice 1","Choice 2","Choice 3")
mylist<- setNames(as.list(seq(1,length(varnames))),varnames)
mylist
$`Choice 1`
[1] 1
$`Choice 2`
[1] 2
$`Choice 3`
[1] 3
```

Now you can update your selectInputs dynamically!

Answer (score 1):

I edited your post to clarify the question and improve legibility.

If I understood you correctly, you are attempting to update the name (and only the name) of that list element, whose value is 1.

```
mylist = list("Choice 1"=1, "Choice 2"=2, "Choice 3"=3)
var = "SimpleTest"
mylist
# $`Choice 1`
# [1] 1
# $`Choice 2`
# [1] 2
# $`Choice 3`
# [1] 3
```

If so, the following code will do that. Assign the name of that list element which has the value 1, the string saved in variable *var*:

```
names(mylist)[which(mylist==1)]=var
mylist
# $SimpleTest
# [1] 1
# $`Choice 2`
# [1] 2
# $`Choice 3`
# [1] 3
```